# Editing of task.json in VSCode for holding external terminal after executing code in C

Tags: c++, c, json, visual-studio-code, terminal

I tried to run code in external terminal in VSCode, it run but the moment the code executed...the console of the external terminal disappeared.
Want it to hold unless I press some key.
I tried to create a task in `task.json`

```
{
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Run this C program",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe -g3 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\" && start powershell \"& \"${fileDirname}\"\\.\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe; pause",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
```

The output comes as
[Output on powershell console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQjbm.png)

P.S. - I've installed C/C++ extension and I don't want to add getch() to the code nor want to use any other extension(like CodeRunner, etc).

How to make this work? Do point out mistakes and provide their solution. I'm new in this.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it is not possible in this IDE.
Windows itself closes the console when last attached process terminates:

From Windows documentation:

> A console is closed when the last process attached to it terminates or
> calls FreeConsole.

So you need to add some code at the end of the program to prevent its termination.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this in your codes:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main{
system("pause");
return 0;}
```